# Access files from SD card (Android 8.1) from computer

Tags: external-sd, 8.1-oreo

I am using an additional SD card on my Android 8.1 phone. It is not formatted as internal memory, and I would like to keep it this way in case my phone fails.

The problem I now face is that I can't access photos in DCIM/Camera on this SD card through my computer. I tried connecting through mtp, and also by running a server (sshelper) on my phone. Unfortunately, the files remain invisible.

I have read that this is "by design", but it seems ridiculous to not be able to copy files from a storage area to my computer. Is there a reasonably simple way to achieve this?

Comment: by design one must unlock screen first